# im getting an error when i try to send data to my database when converting to json i think. how do i convert string to json

Tags: java, android, sql, json, database

I'm getting this when I click the register button in my app.

```
10-20 20:32:13.688 9146-9146/asylum.lotto.steed.codelotto W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-20 20:32:13.689 9146-9146/asylum.lotto.steed.codelotto W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
    at asylum.lotto.steed.codelotto.login.SignUpActivity$1$1.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:51)
10-20 20:32:13.690 9146-9146/asylum.lotto.steed.codelotto W/System.err:     at asylum.lotto.steed.codelotto.login.SignUpActivity$1$1.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:47)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
     10-20 20:32:13.691 9146-9146/asylum.lotto.steed.codelotto W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
```

I think the problem somewhere in my signup java class. I'm fairly new to the whole database thing but I think there's a problem converting to JSON.

```
 register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = regname.getText().toString();
                final String username = regusername.getText().toString();
                final String password = regpassword.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListeer = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if(success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SigninActivity.class);
                                SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };


                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, responseListeer);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUpActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: What line is raising the exception? Most likely you get a string back that is not (valid) JSON. So, look at that line and inspect the value you're trying to convert to JSON.

Comment: its saying these 2 lines are wrong

Comment: Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>()

Comment: JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: Yes. So, have you printed out (or otherwise inspected) the content of `response`? What is in that string?

Comment: Thanks for the help I made a mistake in the back end and it was sending out HTML not json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when sending data from a server it sends it in html unless you add a header and create a data array. I did not do those things in the backend